# Bootstrap Modals sign in and log in error handler with Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, user-interface, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am struggling to show/hide the modal form when the user input is rejected from the validation.

There are two bugs that I need to manage.

**The first** bug is when I submit one of the two forms to authenticate the user if it is submitted with some errors, both modals are displayed back, and the error message is displayed over one of the two dialog boxes.

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

**The second** bug is that when I am handling other form errors both modals appear.

[image: example 3]

I tried to change the id and the name attributes of the inputs tag but it didn't help rather I was more confused because I had to change more values on the backend and I end up screwing more things up. 
I still think is the best way how to proceed.

```
@if ( (Route::current()->getName() != 'login' and 'register') and (count($errors) > 0 and !empty('singinForm')))
     <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#signin_dialog').modal('show');
          $('#login_dialog').modal('hide');
       });
</script> 
@endif
```

This is one method I used to handle the modal `show` and `hide` but it does not work properly

**signin_modal.blade.php**

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="signin_dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Register') }}</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" id="singinForm">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group row">

                    <!-- name input -->
                    <input placeholder="Name" id="nameSignin" type="text" class="form-control input_box @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                    @error('nameSignin')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="text-align:center">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror

                    <!-- email input -->
                    <input placeholder="E-Mail Address" id="emailSignin" type="email" class="form-control input_box @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                    @error('emailSignin')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="text-align:center">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror

                    <!-- password input -->
                    <input placeholder="Password" id="passwordSignin" type="password" class="form-control input_box @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                    <input placeholder="Confirm Password" id="signin-password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control input_box" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                    @error('passwordSignin')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="text-align:center">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror

                    @if ( (Route::current()->getName() != 'login' and 'register') and (count($errors) > 0 and !empty('singinForm')))
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('#signin_dialog').modal('show');
                            $('#login_dialog').modal('hide');
                        });
                    </script>
                    @endif

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="button_box btn-primary">{{ __('Register') }}</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button_box btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login_dialog">Log in</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**login_modal.blade.php**

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="login_dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Login') }}</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" id="loginForm">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input placeholder="E-Mail Address" id="email" type="email" class="form-control input_box @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                    @error('email')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="text-align:center">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                    <input placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control input_box @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                    @error('password')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="text-align:center">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Recover Password') }}
                    </a>
                    @endif

                    @if ( (Route::current()->getName() != 'login' and 'register') and count($errors) > 0 and !empty('loginForm') )
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('#login_dialog').modal('show');
                            $('#signin_dialog').modal('hide');
                        });

                    </script>
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="button_box btn-primary">{{ __('Login') }}</button>
                            <button class="button_box btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#signin_dialog" href="#signin_dialog">Sign in</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change the error class for register form
from:

```
form-control input_box @error('email') is-invalid @enderror
```

to:

```
form-control input_box @error('emailRegister') is-invalid @enderror
```

and then

```
@error('emailRegister')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="text-align:center">
       <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
@enderror
```

do this from all fields.